# c++ how to return a ptr to int from a pointer which is pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct

i am c++ beginner student, i have a problem in my c++ lab assignment.
I have no ideas how to return a pointer to int from a pointer, which is pointer to the struct.

my header file

```
class list {
public:
/* Returns a pointer to the integer field
   pointing to the first node found in list
   with value val. Returns 0 otherwise */
int *find(int val);

private:
list_node *the_list;
}
```

my cpp file

```
int* list::find(int val)
{
    while(the_list)
    {
        if(the_list->value == val)
        {
            // i try to return the pointer that is type pointer to int.
            // the_list is a pointer to a struct type call list_node.

            int * ptr = the_list;
            return ptr;
        }
        the_list = the_list->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct list_node  
{
    int value;                 // data portion
    list_node *next;            // pointer next portion
    list_node *previous;       // pointer previous portion
};
```

Comment: Post compilable code please. You missed a `;`.

Comment: sorry , i can't post whole code, this just part of it.

Comment: Then make a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware your find function moves the pointer to the internal list which is bad. You should use a private variable, and return the address of the `value` member:

```
int* list::find(int val)
{
    for(list_node *node = the_list; node != nullptr; node = node->next)
    {
        if(node->value == val)
        {
            // i try to return the pointer that is type pointer to int.
            // the_list is a pointer to a struct type call list_node.

            return &node->value;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: i never though of for loop, to make my code more neat, thank

Comment: i don't quite understand "return &node->value;"  it return the value of address?

Comment: Other way around, it returns the address of value.

Answer (score 3):

`the_list` is not a pointer to `int`, it's a pointer to `list_node`, so `int *ptr = the_list;` is not correct.

To get a pointer to the value, do:

```
int *ptr = &(the_list->value);
```

Comment: BTW, are the parenthesis really necessary?

Comment: int *ptr = &(the_list->value);

meaning get the address of value contain?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.

Comment: `&(any variable)` returns the address of that variable.